# Do settlers need ammunition?

Tags: fallout-4

Do I need to supply my settlers with ammunition if I give them a new gun, I know that followers require ammunition but does the same apply for settlers.

Why?

> I'd like to role play and give all my settlers Institute weapons so that each fight in my settlements becomes a disco. But I don't have fusion cells to give to them all.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> [Settlers] don't consume ammunition provided they have at least one
> unit of the correct ammunition for their weapon. The same holds true
> with grenades. The only exceptions are the missile launcher or Fat
> Man, as these are tagged with "NPCs Consume Ammo".

Source: Nukapedia, "[Settler](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Settler_(Fallout_4)#Settlers_in_allied_settlements)" article

Try giving a settler a minigun and a 5mm round. =)

Comment: In my limited experience, they do consume ammo for the minigun, but at a ridiculously low rate. I once noticed that one was not using his minigun and when I checked his inventory, he was out of bullets. I haven't experimented any more than this though.

Comment: @winny seems more likely that a random glitch caused them to drop an item.  This is a fallout game, random glitches are traditional.

Comment: @Yakk Ah! That would explain it. I usually equip my settlers with ~50 of the correct ammo type but more for the ones receiving heavy and often attacks of super mutants and thus I equip them with miniguns and misile launchers. I'll take your input and give minigunners the same amount as the others in the future.

Answer (score 6):

I belive that if you give a settler a gun with 1+ ammunition it will be unlimited. I have personally tested. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this by giving some of my settlers one ammo only then attacking them. they were able to shoot me as much as they wanted without running out